# I can not refer to javascript in my html with src=""

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and Javascript. What I am testing is to hit a button, then refer to a JS-script. But when I open my website, it keeps throwing "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hello", `hello` is the function which I defined in the script. The webpage is deployed with docker.

I tried to change the src path many times but  still an error

Here is the homepage.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to sort the list alphabetically:</p>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
        if(typeof jQuery!=='undefined'){
            console.log('jQuery Loaded');
        }
        else{
            console.log('not loaded yet');
        }
</script>
<button onclick="hello('JLKLJSDLFJKSDLKFKJLSDJKLFJLKS')">HAHA7</button>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
<p>The date today is {{.Date}}</p>
<p>And the time is {{.Time}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script:

```js
hello = function (arg) {
    document.write(arg);
}
```

And here is my file structure:

```
.
├── dockerfile
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── k8s
│   ├── alb-ingress-controller.yaml
│   ├── aws-auth-cm.yaml
│   ├── eks-admin-cluster-role-binding.yaml
│   ├── eks-admin-service-account.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── inventory-deployment.yaml
│   ├── inventory-namespace.yaml
│   ├── inventory-service.yaml
│   └── rbac-role.yaml
├── README.md
├── server.go
└── template
    ├── ec2.html
    ├── homepage.html
    ├── js
    │   ├── sort.js
    │   └── test.js
    ├── login.html
    ├── rds.html
    └── redis.html
```

Now the error is when i hit the button "HAHA7" it is saying "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hello", thanks everyone!

Comment: check your typo <srcript. it should be <script

Comment: Thanks man, i am stupid enough but i still got the error after correcting the word

Comment: Also try to not get angry/upset/mad. You will get a TON of senseless, meaningless error messages in this field of work and if you start gettign angry and naming things in a particular way... it is not healthy, relax, step from the pc for a few minutes, come back with a clear mind. Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: I am so sorry , thank you for your advice. I will do in a healthy way next time!

Comment: Please edit your question, show us what is the current version of your script and explain what the exact error is now.

Comment: Your JS is in a folder called "template" that suggests your HTTP server is not designed to serve content in it as static files. Find out how to serve static files with your HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an absolute link, moving your script tags to the bottom of the page and using JavaScript events instead of inline events, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to sort the list alphabetically:</p>
  <button id="my-button">HAHA7</button> 
  <p>The date today is {{.Date}}</p>
  <p>And the time is {{.Time}}</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('jQuery Loaded');
    } else{
      console.log('not loaded yet');
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/test.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("#my-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
      someBadWord('JLKLJSDLFJKSDLKFKJLSDJKLFJLKS');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you but error still. It seems 'src="/js/test.js"' is not working here?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to sort the list alphabetically:</p>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script> 
  <script>
    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('jQuery Loaded');
    } else {
      console.log('not loaded yet');
    }
  </script>
  <button id="myButton">HAHA7</button> 
  <script language="javascript" src="js/test.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <p>The date today is {{.Date}}</p>
  <p>And the time is {{.Time}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Listener assigned to button
  $("myButton").click({
    param1: "JLKLJSDLFJKSDLKFKJLSDJKLFJLKS"
  }, sht);


  // Function
  function sht(event) {
    document.write(event.data.param1)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i followed your reply but still got the error. I click "js/test.js" in console , it somehow points to the homepage.html...

Answer (score -1):

check below code:

```js
stuff = function(arg) {
  document.write(arg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to sort the list alphabetically:</p>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('jQuery Loaded');
    } else {
      console.log('not loaded yet');
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick="stuff('JLKLJSDLFJKSDLKFKJLSDJKLFJLKS')">HAHA7</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
  <p>The date today is {{.Date}}</p>
  <p>And the time is {{.Time}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your code but still got the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: XXXX"